# How do i properly write a ajax reponse

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I know this is a bad title for my question but what i am trying to do is reply to Autocomplete  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete#API_Documentation

Instead of getting many elements i only receive "Array". I know this is obviously wrong bc of the way echo works but how do i echo in such a way this autocomplete works?

mydoc.html

```
$().ready(function() {
    $("#suggest3").autocomplete("reply.php", {
        multiple: true,
        mustMatch: true,
        autoFill: true
    });

});
```

reply.php

```
<?php
// Fill up array with names
$a[]="Anna";
$a[]="Brittany";
$a[]="Amanda";

  $response=$a;

echo $response;
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Send it as JSON or convert it to a string- otherwise php just prints the object type.

JSON:

```
echo json_encode($a);
```

Array:

```
echo implode(',',$a);
```

Comment: String:

echo implode(',',$a);

Answer (score 1):

Tonycore is right on with the json_encode() answer.  I just wanted to add that when returning JSON it's also good to set the header correctly:

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($a);
```